# compile python 3.8.7, numpy 1.19 and scipy WITHOUT lapack, blas from source

Tags: python, scipy, lapack

I like to compile python 3.8.7 from scratch and add numpy, scipy.
Python compiles fine, numpy as well (disabled LAPACK=None, BLAS=None, ATLAS=None).
If i compile scipy i run into the following error:

```
File "scipy/linalg/setup.py", line 20, in configuration
raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found
```

I intentionally don't want a LAPACK, BLAS, ATLAS dependency!

Is there a way of disabling these libraries?

```
setenv PYHOME  "/path/to/my/python"
FFI_VERSION        "3.3"
PYTHON_VERSION     "3.8.7"
CYTHON_VERSION     "0.29.21"
NUMPY_VERSION      "1.19.5"
PYBIND11_VERSION   "2.6.1"
SCIPY_VERSION      "1.5.4"

setenv BLAS             "None"
setenv ATLAS            "None"
setenv LAPACK           "None"
setenv NPY_BLAS_ORDER   ""
setenv NPY_LAPACK_ORDER ""

${PYHOME}/bin/python3 setup.py build
${PYHOME}/bin/python3 setup.py install --prefix=${PYHOME}
```

Comment: Installing via e.g. yum install lapack etc. is not an option,

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/building/linux.html) says:

> Before building, you will also need to install packages that NumPy and SciPy depend on

> **BLAS and LAPACK libraries** (optional but strongly recommended for NumPy, **required for SciPy**): typically ATLAS + OpenBLAS, or MKL.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!

```
setenv PYTHON_VERSION     "3.6.4"
setenv CYTHON_VERSION     "0.24.1"
setenv NUMPY_VERSION      "1.11.1"
setenv SCIPY_VERSION      "0.18.1"
```

this version/setup works without LAPACK etc. disabled by the LAPACK,BLAS,ATLAS=None switches. So this hard requirement of the Lapack dependence of SciPy was introduced later...